how to convert multiple columns to one column
i have issued in excel. For example i have table like this



Column A
Column B
Column C




Johny
1
2


Celin

4



I want to make new table, which merge column B and Column C like this



Column A
Column D




Jhony
1


Jhony
2


Celin
4



Anyone can help me please?
I'm having trouble to find effective ways to solved this problem.

Power Query (aka Get & Transform) > Unpivot Columns.

Or: =HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(B1:C2,A1:A2),3),TOCOL(B1:C2,1))
